# Read the braille on Khatun and Prarie's father's faces (The OA)

Tags: the-oa

In episode 4, Prarie/The OA meets Khatun again, she appears to have little bumps which look like braille.

This is a longshot but can anyone read any of this?

[image]

A high resolution version can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GXh5.jpg)

**UPDATE**

It's just been pointed out (thanks @user1118321) that there is also braille on the father's face also, I think this one is too difficult as the face is small relative to the screen:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

This [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheOA/comments/5j5gs7/the_braille_on_khatun_and_the_oas_fathers_face/) thread seems to think it maybe *who if* then *because* and *angel* but it's ambiguous for the father:

by user philaj9

> Ok here's what I have so far: The braille is in German. The top row on
>   Khatuns forehead says "wer wenn' which translates to 'who if'. I can't
>   figure out the bottom row on her forehead. Her right cheek, left
>   screen I can see only close to her nose. Top says 'denn' or 'because'
>   and bottom says 'engel' or ' angel'. Left cheek, right side of screen,
>   I can only see another 'engel'. For the dad, I can only make out his
>   right cheek, on the left side of the screen to say '5 as leere jene'
>   which according to Google translate is '5 as empty ones'. I've been
>   seeing a lot of braille characters that I just can't find in any
>   alphabet online, one in particular that looks like the bottom right
>   angle of a square. Hope this helps.

** UPDATE 3 **

Seems there is more braille here on the wall (thanks @starry for pointing this one out):

[image]

Comment: Note that The OA's father also has braille on his face in the scene where he appears in the other dimension. I'd be interested to know what it says, as well.

Comment: @user1118321 I never noticed that until now, I'll upload an image but it's going to be difficult to read that one as the face is small relative to the frame unlike the one above

Comment: What about the braille in the counselor's office in episode 7?

Answer (score 4):

The Braille in the office says Rachel.

Since I only speak English I couldn't decipher the face Braille on one cheek but it looks like "hirt meg" or "hinrt meg". It's hard to tell because of the shift in cell placement, because it's not on paper.

One word on the chin looks like "genl" or "genth" - again hard to tell.

"hinrt" means "hints" in German and I see "engel" on that cheek too which is "Angel".

If I had a clearer image I could tell you the letters.

Comment: "hinrt" is not a German word. Where did you get the idea from?