# The OA last episode - FBI Agent's involvement?

Tags: the-oa

Reflecting on the final episode of the OA, in which French enters Prairie's house while her family are staying at a motel, to search for clues to her whereabouts.

He discovers four books - a book on Russian Oligarchs, Homer's Odyssey, a book about angels, and one (I believe) about NDEs.

When he finds these he is crestfallen and believes that he and the other four have been taken for a ride. He enters the bathroom, where he hallucinates that he is Homer.

Then, upon leaving, is greeted by the FBI Agent, who seems to comfort him rather than berate him for breaking & entering.

Now this could say that the FBI Agent never believed Prairie's story, and believes her to be a very vulnerable individual who has cooked up a story to explain an otherwise vague traumatic event. He is grateful to French for believing in Prairie and giving her somewhere to offload grief.

I started wondering:
Why was he at the house? In the middle of the night, when no one's home?

Comment: The real question is why was the FBI agent there: all the others are potential answers or qualifiers. Focus on the reason he was there and the question is better.

Answer (score 6):

Because he's not an FBI agent. This is speculation on my part, but nothing about him seems legit. He works out of an office building with almost no other people. His own office looks as though it was abandoned by a failed company and they're squatting there.

Furthermore, if he is a psychologist or even just a counselor, he's being highly unethical. (Not that that's out of the question, but it certainly makes it seem like he's not really what he says.)

We know that Dr. Happ knows other people doing similar work. It's not out of the question that some other doctor or group (possibly even a group of escaped former captives) is looking for Dr. Happ and others like him to bring to light what they're doing.

It also appears there may be some relationship between Rachel (the other woman who's a captive of Dr. Happ) and the "FBI" agent. When he's at his office, there's a scene where he's standing next to a wall with what appears to be some anchors that held up a sign. But if you read the anchors as if they were braille, [they spell out "Rachel"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65893/read-the-braille-on-khatun-and-praries-fathers-faces-the-oa).

So something's not right about him, and it probably goes beyond just being creepy or overeager to do his job as an FBI agent. Simply put, I think he's something else entirely.

Comment: Fascinating idea, but I'm not convinced. Any other corroborating evidence?

Answer (score 2):

In *Part II*, Episode 6, "Mirror Mirror", the FBI agent and also Prairie's counselor, Elias Rahim says that he's been "sent to help OA" and guides the group on what to do. This hints that he might also be an interdimensional traveler.

In *Part I*, he was most likely there to talk to French, console and guide him, to help OA.

Dialogue from S02E06:

> Elias Rahim: You remember where we met?
>
> French: Yeah.
>
> Elias: You never asked me what I was doing there.
>
> French: At OA's house?
>
> Elias: Yeah.
>
> French: Okay. So why were you?
>
> Elias: Why was I what?
>
> French: Why were you at her house?
>   ...
>
> [Dialogue between the group and Elias where Elias helps clarify how dimensions are connected and what the group needs to do.]
>   ...
>
> Elias: Now you've got what you need.
>
> BBA: I thought I was losing my mind.
>
> Elias: You're not.
>
> Elias: You're just finding new rooms inside it.
>
> BBA: We are meant to go to Treasure Island.
>
> BBA: Why are you helping us?
>
> Elias: I've been sent to help her.
>
> Elias: She's gonna need it.